# flexlayout problem with mobile resolution and container

Tags: css

HELLO I have the following structure in my flexbox

header
main
footer

and in my main I have a container to centralize the content But when I use smaller resolutions it is problematic as in the photo:

[image]

code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "100%" }}>
      <div style={{ flex: "none", background: "blue", height: "140px" }}>a</div>
      <div
        style={{
          padding: "0 30px",
          margin: "0 auto",
          background: "red",
          maxWidth: "1240px",
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <h2>
          Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi..
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div style={{ flex: "none", background: "yellow", height: "40px" }}>
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css reset:

```
body > #root > div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-feather-cmxiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width property does not include padding, so when your middle element includes a 30px padding on left and right sides AND is also set to 100% width, it causes an x-overflow. If you want the middle element's entire bounding box to be 100% width, you can do the following styles:

```
  <div
    style={{
      padding: "0 30px",
      margin: "0 auto",
      background: "red",
      maxWidth: "1240px",
      width: "calc(100% - 60px)"
    }}
  >
```